# Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebugAndroidTest'

Tags: android, cucumber, android-espresso

I am trying to setup a framework in Android Studio with Espresso and Cucumber.

When I am trying to run Android test configuration, the build fails giving me the following exception:

Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebugAndroidTest'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is  my bundle.gradle file dependencies.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "testapp.drayson.com.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   // multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "testapp.drayson.com.testapp.Instrumentation"
}

sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3')
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'

//Cucumber
androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.0@jar'
androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.4'
androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.1.4') {
    exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    exclude module: 'cucumber-core'
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:1.2.4') {
}
androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.4') {
    exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
}
androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3') {
}

//Espresso
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1') {
    exclude module: 'junit'
    exclude module: 'runner'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    exclude module: 'espresso-core'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

}

Comment: I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

You just need to import it and then you will be able to run your tests written in Gherkin.

Answer (score 1):

try adding **multiDexEnabled**  as **true** in your

```
buildType{ release{ multiDexEnabled true} }
```

hope it works for you..

Comment: Hi @Lewis Hai, thanks for the reply. I will try and post back the result.